# gradle: migrate spring app to a multiproject build

Tags: java, spring, gradle, multi-project

I followed this [tutorial](http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/). This runs fine.
I would like to create a multiproject build with one project that contains this spring application. So I added this project to a subfolder called `web` of this multiproject build, added a settings.gradle file:

```
include 'web'
```

As well as a build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'application'
mainClassName = "hello.Application"

jar {
  baseName = 'VoPro'
}

dependencies {
  compile project(':web')
}
```

However, when i run `$ gradle build`, i get the error:

```
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':runtime'.
> Cannot resolve external dependency org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web: because no repositories are defined.
  Required by:
      :test:unspecified > test:web:unspecified
```

Why can't gradle find any repositories?

EDIT: The `web` subproject contains the following build.gradle file (like in the tutorial):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.2.2.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

jar {
    baseName = 'gs-rest-service'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    testCompile("junit:junit")
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '1.11'
}
```

Comment: try `include ':web'`

Comment: @BorisBera In the settings file you mean? Just tried it, seems to be fine either way.

Comment: I noticed i linked the wrong tutorial, this should now be fixed

Answer (score 2):

You should add a `build.gradle` file under the *web* project itself and configure appropriate repositories there. Or add a *global* `build.gradle` and the following piece of code in it:

```
allprojects {
   repositories {
      mavenCentral()
      mavenLocal()
   }
}
```

Basically the multimodule project should have the following structure

```
-- build.gradle // all projects configuration
-- settings.gradle //includes all modules 
-- module1
  -- build.gradle
-- module2
  -- build.gradle
-- modulen
  -- build.gradle
..
```

After discussion in comments:
You need to specify the dependency along with version, no idea why:

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.2.2.RELEASE")
```

Comment: I have a build.gradle file in the subproject `web`, sorry if this wasn't clear. It is the exact same as the one in the tutorial.

Comment: I included this build.gradle file in my question.

Comment: If I include those repositories i get:
    `Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':runtime'.`
    `> Could not find org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:`
      `Searched in the following locations:`
        `.......`

Comment: Is the project we're talking about online?

Comment: I have solved the problem by moving the web subproject to the root project (which was empty). This solution seems not as elegant, but it does work.

Comment: @jvermeulen, thanks. Good to know it. Quite weird this dependency resolution in that case.